# Is there any difference between tee and >> when using echo?

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, tee

Is there any difference beteween doing:

```
echo "hahaha" >> file1
```

and

```
echo "hahaha" |tee -a file1
```

?

Yes, I noticed that I cannot write to write protected files even aith `sudo echo`, but I can if I `sudo tee`. Thanks.

Comment: More i/o usage, more memory usage, more cpu cycles, more characters in terminal.

Comment: tee starts an extra process and means you get a copy of stdout as well. It also lets you use `sudo` to write to a file you don't have write permission on.

Comment: to use ```echo``` with ```sudo``` use this syntax: ```sudo /usr/bin/bash -c 'echo "hehe" > file.ext'```

Answer (score 28):

There's no difference in the sense that the data *in the file* will be the same if `echo` and `tee` are executed successfully and if the file is writable by the current user.

The `tee` command would additionally produce output on *its* standard output, showing the text that would also be appended to the file.  This would not happen in the first command.

Another difference is that if the file can *not* be written to, then the first command, with the redirection, would not even run the `echo`, whereas the `echo` *would* run in the second command, but `tee` would fail in writing to the file (`tee` would still produce text on the terminal though).

This could be significant in the case where you run some long running process that produces output:

```
long_running_thing >>file
```

This would not even start `long_running_thing` if `file` was not writable.

```
long_running_thing | tee -a file
```

This would execute `long_running_thing` and it would run to the end, but no output would be saved into `file` if it wasn't writable (and the output would additionally be written to the terminal from `tee`).

The next thing to be aware of, which you hinted at in the end of the question, is that

```
sudo echo hello >>file
```

won't work if `file` isn't writable by the *current* user.  This is because the redirection is processed *before* the command is executed (see above).

To append to a root-owned file, use

```
echo hello | sudo tee -a file
```

Here, we run `tee` as root.  The `echo` does not need to be executed by root, but the utility that actually writes to the file needs to be executed as root (or as whatever user owns the file) if it's not owned by the current user.

Another possibility would be to use

```
sudo sh -c 'echo hello >>file'
```

or

```
echo hello | sudo sh -c 'cat >>file'
```

This would use a redirection to append data to the file, but in this case, the shell that performs the redirection is running as root, so it would not fail in appending/creating the file due to restrictive permissions/ownership (it may still fail if e.g. `file` is the name of a directory).

Answer (score 11):

Tee is primarily used to **redirect the output to multiple files** instead of invoking a copy command separately.

E.g.:

```
wc -l | tee -a file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

You can elevate privilege to the tee command alone instead of the whole process, where as >> is initiated even before elevated privilege kicks in.